# Bookmark specific text on a webpage in Chrome in a drop down

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

How can I bookmark to a specific part of a webpage that is part of a drop down in Chrome? I have tried the chrome extension link to fragment. It doesn't work. Here's a website example with trying to bookmark to the gas station prices after clicking on Gas Stations.

https://www.costco.com/warehouse-locations/w-jacksonville-fl-1294.html

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

The page is designed to load the collapsible panels collapsed.  You need to click on them to expand them.  The information does exist in the page at load time, just hidden.  If you parse the HTML using a tool you could theoretically pull the values you want based on the html code.

Example

```
<span class="gas-type">Regular</span><br>
<span class="h3-style-guide">$2.91<sup>9</sup></span>
```

and

```
<span class="gas-type">Premium</span><br>
<span class="h3-style-guide">$3.31<sup>9</sup></span>
```

Excerpted from

```
<div id="service-collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" aria-labelledby="service-header-1" aria-expanded="true" style="">
  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="col-xs-12 gas-title">
      <span class="h5-style-guide">Gas Hours</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 working-hours-section">

      <div class="col-xs-3 col-xl-2 padding-left-0">
        <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mon-Fri. ">Mon-Fri. </time>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-9 col-xl-10 padding-left-0">
        <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="6:00am - 9:00pm">6:00am - 9:00pm</time>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 working-hours-section">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-xl-2 padding-left-0">
        <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Sat. ">Sat. </time>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-9 col-xl-10 padding-left-0">
        <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="7:00am - 7:00pm">7:00am - 7:00pm</time>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 working-hours-section">

      <div class="col-xs-3 col-xl-2 padding-left-0">
        <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Sun. ">Sun. </time>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-9 col-xl-10 padding-left-0">
        <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="7:00am - 7:00pm">7:00am - 7:00pm</time>
      </div>                                                                

    </div>                                              

    <div class="row col-xl-8 gas-price-section">

      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <span class="gas-type">Regular</span><br>
        <span class="h3-style-guide">$2.91<sup>9</sup></span>
      </div>    

      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <span class="gas-type">Premium</span><br>
        <span class="h3-style-guide">$3.31<sup>9</sup></span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-8 diclaimer-section">
      <p class="disclaimer-text-font" automation-id="gasPriceDisclaimerLabel"> 
        Prices shown here are updated frequently, but may not reflect the
        price at the pump at the time of purchase. All sales will be made
        at the price posted on the pumps at each Costco location at the 
        time of purchase.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```